# Path inside git repository

Tags: git, bash, zsh

I want to obtain the path inside the current git repository, including the root folder itself.

So if my repository lives at `~/Projects/somerepo`, and I am at `~/Projects/somerepo/src/js`, I want to obtain `somerepo/src/js`.

Some commands that may be useful:

- `git rev-parse --show-prefix` gives `src/js`
- `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` gives `/Users/gberger/Projects/somerepo/src/js`
- `git rev-parse --show-cdup` gives `../../`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate basename of toplevel directory and the `--show-prefix` output

```
echo $(basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel))/$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)
```

Comment: Spent 5 minutes playing with these exact options, solved the problem, came back to post answer... And you were faster. Haha. I did add ` | sed 's/\/$//'` to the end to remove trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested):

```
pwd=$(pwd | tr -d)
relative=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup | tr -d)
absolute=$(readlink -f $pwd$relative)
echo $absolute
```

Comment: Oh, realpath isn't shipped with Linux anymore... See my Edit

Comment: I'm on OSX by the way